# Instanciar classe passando apenas alguns parâmetros em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde pessoal

Eu criei uma classe bem simples em python com um construtor `__init__`. O construtor espera receber 3 parâmetros, sendo que os 3 possuem valor default.
  Gostaria de saber como faço para instanciar a classe passando apenas os parâmetro 1 e 3.

Se instancio desta forma funciona :

```
p = Person('Wagner')
```

Assim também funciona

```
p = Person('Wagner','xxx')
```

Porém desta forma ocorre erro:

```
p = Person('Wagner', ,27)
```

Erro:

```
File "Person.py", line 11
p = Person('Wagner', ,27)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Se eu instanciar desta forma também funciona

```
p = Person('Wagner','' ,27)
```

mas supondo que eu tivesse 10 parâmetros com valores *default* e quero passar apenas o número 7,9,10 como eu faria ? Seria obrigado a passar `''` nos vazios, mesmo eles tendo um valor default no construtor ?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name='not defined', last_name='not defined', age=0):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age

    def printPerson(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name + "\nLast Name: " + 
              self.last_name + "\nAge: " + str(self.age))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode declarar o nome do argumento que você está passando em Python.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name = 'not defined', last_name = 'not defined', age = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age

p = Person(name = 'Wagner', age = 27)
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você tiver muitos argumentos que precisem ser passados para uma classe, ou mesmo uma função, é recomendável que você outra abordagem que a dos argumentos posicionais. Talvez manter `nome` como argumento posicional (e obrigatório) e deixando os demais como argumentos com palavra chave (e opcionais):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = kwargs.get("last_name", "n/a")
        self.age = kwargs.get("age", 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.last_name} | {self.age}"
```

E um teste básico:

```
a = Person("Wagner")
b = Person("Wagner", last_name="Rodrigues")
c = Person("Wagner", age=27)
d = Person("Wagner", last_name="Rodrigues", age=27)

for i in [a, b, c, d]:
    print(i)
```

Que retorna:

```
Wagner n/a | 0
Wagner Rodrigues | 0
Wagner n/a | 27
Wagner Rodrigues | 27
```

Desta maneira novos argumentos que precisem ser passados para dentro da classe através de palavras chaves e no construtor você define qual o valor padrão caso ele seja omitido.